# I get this error when try to discard change of new appointment on outlook online

Tags: typescript, office365, typeerror, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I got a `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError`

When I try to:

- go to outlook online `https://outlook.office365.com/` > calendar > select datetime
- open new appointment window > set `Repeat` = `Every day`
- open my add-in > a task pane with my add-in content shown
- close new appointment window & [try to discard change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92AHl.png)
- then I get this message [There was something that went wrong with the application. Please refresh your browser window to continue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZOMc.png)
- I inspect & found this [Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'IsMeeting' of null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOil9.png) from this code `eventToDelete.IsMeeting && responseSent && !eventToDelete.IsCancelled` [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKwVV.png)

this is the fullpath to the file cause the error that I can find `owa/./packages/common/controls/packages/calendar/data/owa-calendar-event-notification-bar/lib/utils/showUndoNotificationForInstantDelete.ts`

**UPDATE:**
I will not face this error if I comment out the code that set custom property like this

```
let customProperties: Office.CustomProperties;
if (this._appointment.CustomUid && this._appointment.CustomUid != '') {
    //customProperties.set(this._customUidKey, this._appointment.CustomUid);
    //customProperties.saveAsync();
}
```

Then I think this is a bug of OWA while handle recurring appointment with custom property, right?

Appreciate all your help.

Comment: Hello, thanks for reporting this issue. We could repro it. We also have added this issue to our backlog; however unfortunately we don't have any timelines to share for the fix. Thank you.